# How can i count occurrences in a list using this function in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've found multiple ways of doing this already but haven't been able to apply those here since i'm not familiar with the language yet, so maybe a more direct question could help

```
   def occurrences(cars: List[Char]): List [(Char, Int)] = {
    
    . . .

  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not familiar with the language, this answer will probably not help you very much ... but then, it's not very likely that another will. My advice to you would be to grab a book and learn the basics of the language first, before jumping into asking other people to solve random made up problems for you.

As to counting characters in a string, it would be something like this:

```
chars.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `cars` is not a good name for a list of characters :) (I know, just kidding). You should definitely get more into the language and read more about some of the most used functions, like what they are, what they do and why they exist, but just to answer this specific question, you can do this:

###### Approach No.1:

```scala
  def occurrences(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] =
    chars.foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int])(
      (occurrencesMap, newChar) => occurrencesMap.updatedWith(newChar) {
        case Some(count) => Some(count + 1)
        case None => Some(1)
      }
    ).toList
```

###### Explanation:

Basically we're just iterating over the list, and we want to aggregate the data in a structure, where a character is mapped to its number of usages, so we use a `Map[Char, Int]`, and during the iteration, if the aggregator (occurrencesMap in this case) contains the char, we increment it and otherwise we initiate it with 1.

###### Approach No.2:

I can also suggest this one-line approach, but I think the first approach is more beginner-friendly or understandable in some senses:

```scala
def occurrences(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] =
    chars.groupMapReduce[Char, Int](identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _).toList
```

###### Explanation:

As the function name declares `groupMapReduce` first groups the values inside the list by a function, then maps each key occurrence into a value, and then reduce the resulted values for each key, into a single item, so we use `identity` to group the items inside the list, by the value of the character itself, and if a character is found, we basically just found 1 character right? so ignore the value of the character, and just return 1 :D `_ => 1`, and at the end, you would have something like `'c' -> List(1, 1, 1)`, so let's just add them all together, or use `.length` to count the occurrences.

Comment: I would use pattern matching for `updtedWith` even for me the current implementation took me a couple of seconds to understand what was going on.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes, I also used pattern matching in the first version of my answer, but then I realized the pattern is just to increment, so why not `.map`? :D

Comment: I mean, is a matter of readability, for the expert eye it makes sense that `updatedWith` receives an `Option` and returns another one; and, as such, in this case, is a matter of `.map` + `orElse` but that is a lot of mental gymnastics. However, for the novice eye _(and even the expert IMHO)_ the pattern matching is clearer in its intention since is more natural to think about both branches separated, what to do if there is already a value, and what to do when there is none.

Answer (score 1):

As both answers here show, there are plenty of ways to solve this using the stdlib; as I always say the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend.
Also, as both answers suggest, it is recommended that you learn the language.

However, I wanted to show another cool way of solving this problem using **cats**.

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

chars.foldMap(char => Map(char -> 1))
```

`foldMap` is a function added by **cats** to the `List[Char]` that as the name suggests does mapping and folding in the same step.
The folding is done using the default combine operation of the type returned by the map. And the default combine operation of a `Map` is to join both maps and combine values with matching keys using their default combine operation; and for ints that is sum.